# Unity. Do I really need to add Firebase analytics *and* crashlytic sdks?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I want to add only firebase crashlytics to my game.
The firebase guide tells you to add the add the package FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage
and then packages for any other firebase features you want.
So if I follow the guide I should add FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage *and* FirebaseCrashlytics.unitypackage

However, all the packages are about the same size; 90MB, and looking into them, they contain a lot of the same stuff. Eg they all contain the google play services resolver. It looks like each one can function on its own.. and when I import just crashlytics I dont get errors and can build a build that runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashlytics should be able to run in apps that don't also include Analytics. If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to show how you included the package, and details about the problem you get.

If Analytic **is** present in the app, Crashlytics may use that to report certain events. So you'll be missing features such as crash-free statistics, the Latest Release report, and Breadcrumbs.

For more info, see:

- the Firebase documentation on [adding crashlytics to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#add-sdk)
- the Firebase blog post on the [Crashlytics relaunch](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/02/announcing-firebase-crashlytics-sdk-beta.html), specifically this section:

> Combining analytics data and crashes helps you unlock additional insights into your app’s stability. The Firebase Crashlytics SDK works seamlessly with the Google Analytics SDK to provide features such as crash-free statistics, the Latest Release report, and Breadcrumbs. With Breadcrumbs you can see the steps a user took that led to a crash. This insight helps you reproduce and fix issues quickly. Google Analytics replaces Fabric's legacy analytics engine, Answers, so we encourage you to add Google Analytics to your apps.

Comment: I have upgraded my android code from fabric crashlytics to firebase crashlytics and google analytics changes. But After that also I am getting 
 ```Please upgrade to the generally available Firebase Crashlytics SDK to continue getting crash reports in the Firebase console past November 15, 2020. Learn more``` in firebase console.  does it mean I didn't upgraded properly or need to do any changes in firebase console.

Comment: This warning probably means that you're using an older Unity SDK. You should at least upgrade to 6.15.0 (the latest is 6.15.2).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=unity

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity